# How do I pick Screen Resolution and Aspect Ratio in World of Warships?

Tags: world-of-warships

I don't want trial and error to find best screen resolution  'cause World of Warship has too many choices. I screen shot [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Ko-b3XY1wRo?t=324) then "Display" window from my Windows 10 laptop.

[image]

Windows 10

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why are you not using the highest resolution supported by your laptop/monitor?

Comment: @Smock I want resolution to fit screen. "highest resolution supported by your laptop/monitor" didn't work - it extended outside my monitor.

Comment: Is 1024 x 768 the maximum resolution of your laptop? How old is it? (Make / Model ?) I find it hard to believe any laptop decent enough to play Warships only has a 4:3 screen. Perhaps there's another issue at play here (drivers or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the best to use the resolution recommended by Windows (in your case 1024x768), as it knows your monitor capability. If you use other resolutions image may get stretched and that affects game performance. Aspect ratio can be calculated using sites like [this](http://screen-size.info/), if not set by game automatically (your ratio for recommended resolution is 4:3).

Edit: as pointed up that game does not support the recommended resolution you should use the highest resolution with same aspect ratio your monitor supports.

Comment: Based on the aspect ratio, and the fact that 1024 x 768 doesn't seem to be available in the game, I suggest using 1280 x 960. This is the first higher resolution with the same aspect ratio that is available for both your monitor and the game.